# Given a list of strings, create a hashmap with length and string

Tags: java

I am trying to understand a programming question where I am given a list of words for example, (apple, orange, car, can, fuzzy) I would get a hashmap with the length for the key and linkedlist of words for value. For example,

```
(3, {car, can})
(5, {apple, fuzzy})
(6, {orange})
```

How could I build this? I am relatively new to Java and only knows how to read string input and get the length of each string. But very unfamiliar with hashmaps. Could someone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

As Tim Biegeleisen said, here's an approach if you're using Java 8:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

public class CollectByLength {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, List<String>> map = Stream.of("apple", "orange", "car", "can", "fuzzy")
                                        .collect(groupingBy(String::length));

        System.out.println(map); //prints {3=[car, can], 5=[apple, fuzzy], 6=[orange]}
    }
}
```

If you care about the `List` implementation for some reason, the above solution doesn't provide any guarantee on the list implementation. From the doc:

> There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or
>   thread-safety of the Map or List objects returned.

But it's also possible to specify the `List` implementation you need (`LinkedList` here)

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

public class CollectByLength {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, List<String>> map = Stream.of("apple", "orange", "car", "can", "fuzzy")
                                        .collect(groupingBy(String::length, toCollection(LinkedList::new)));

        System.out.println(map); //prints {3=[car, can], 5=[apple, fuzzy], 6=[orange]}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly concise Java 7 approach:

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList("apple", "orange", "car", "can", "fuzzy");
Map<Integer, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

for (String word : words) {
    List<String> wordList = map.get(word.length());
    if (wordList == null) {
        wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
        wordList.add(word);
        map.put(word.length(), wordList);
    }
    else {
        wordList.add(word);
    }
}
```

I will leave it up the experts to give an even leaner Java 8 solution.

Comment: This is what I tried but the hashmap I am looking for needs to be Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>> where the arraylist is a bunch of words of length integer

Comment: The list returned by `singletonList()` is immutable, so that code won't work.

Comment: @JonathanBishop In question you say *"linkedlist"* by now you say `ArrayList`. Which is it?

Comment: The list returned by `Arrays.asList()` is fixed-length, so that code won't work.

Comment: No need to be an expert to give a Java 8 solution, or ?